# Vue.js web component inherit page styles

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, web-component

I'm using vue-cli-service to generate web components as

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc 'components/*.vue'
```

In order to generate a bundle with all components inside that folder. Until now works very well and I can even mount the components on my page

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="/dist/bundle.min.js"></script>
  <my-component></my-component>
```

The problem I'm having is that the web component **doesn't inherit the styling** of the current page.
Imagine I'm working with a bootstrap layout, i would need to import that package within the web component?

Is there any way for me to disable the shadow dom even if for that it sacrifices some functionalities of the wc ? (such as slots, etc. that i'm not going to use)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to do this with `vue-cli-service`.

There is a fork of official Vue Web Component Wrapper [here](https://github.com/cristovao-trevisan/vue-web-component-wrapper). This fork allows you to disable the shadow DOM but that doesn't support the slots.

However, if you want to use that then you cannot use `vue-cli-service`. You will have to setup your own build using **Webpack** or **Rollup**.